# Mysql order by with grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello everyone today i got in to a problem..

first thing i have a two table each table i have "product_seq_id" column and i joined table using the same "product_seq_id"
in the second table there are multiple rows for "product_seq_id" i want only one with below condition

- table2.date_start not be null
- table2.date_start is equal to '0000-00-00' or table2.date_start <= CURDATE()
- table2.date_end is equal to '0000-00-00' or table2.date_start >= CURDATE()
- get highest table2.priority if 2 or more rows match on the same day

I have already did some work.. but the problem is in that it's not taking highest priority number while ordering the column with grouped

//My Query

```
SELECT 
    psp . *, pcp . *
FROM
    sk_product_category_path pcp
        left join
    sk_product_special_price psp ON (psp.product_seq_id = pcp.product_seq_id)
where
    pcp.category_seq_id = 146
        AND psp.product_seq_id IS NOT NULL
        AND CASE
        WHEN
            psp.date_start IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            (psp.date_start = '0000-00-00'
                OR psp.date_start <= CURDATE())
                AND (psp.date_end = '0000-00-00'
                OR psp.date_end >= CURDATE())
        ELSE 1 = 1
    END
group by psp.product_seq_id
order by psp.priority desc
```

---

```
Result Came for above code:
# product_special_price_seq_id, product_special_price, date_start, date_end, priority, product_seq_id, product_category_path_seq_id, product_seq_id, category_seq_id
2309    123123  0000-00-00  0000-00-00  0   3196    1   3196    146
2307    12313   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  0   3197    3   3197    146
```

---

```
Result I wanted:
# product_special_price_seq_id, product_special_price, date_start, date_end, priority, product_seq_id, product_category_path_seq_id, product_seq_id, category_seq_id
2309    12200   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  1   3196    2   3196    146
2307    12313   0000-00-00  0000-00-00  0   3197    3   3197    146
```

// Table Data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sk_product_category_path` (
  `product_category_path_seq_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_seq_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_seq_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_category_path_seq_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_seq_id` (`product_seq_id`,`category_seq_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `sk_product_category_path` (`product_category_path_seq_id`, `product_seq_id`, `category_seq_id`) VALUES
(1, 3196, 146),
(2, 3197, 146),
(3, 3198, 146);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sk_product_special_price` (
  `product_special_price_seq_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_special_price` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_end` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_seq_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_special_price_seq_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `sk_product_special_price` (`product_special_price_seq_id`, `product_special_price`, `date_start`, `date_end`, `priority`, `product_seq_id`) VALUES
(1, 12313, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 0, 3197),
(2, 12200, '2014-02-11', '2014-02-11', 1, 3197),
(3, 123123, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 0, 3196);
```

Comment: You are using a MySQL `group by` extension that allows unaggregated columns in the `select` of an aggregation query.  Because MySQL *explicitly* warns against doing this when the values are not equal in all rows in the group (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html), I think you should fix your query to avoid this unsupported behavior.

Comment: Issue is with your group by...most other SQL languages will actually throw an error instead of executing what you have.  A group by statement must contain all rows in the select statement that isn't an aggregate of some form.  select psp.*,pcp.* and only group by psp.product_seq_id won't work here...MySQL is just silly enough to try to run it anyway (returns incorrect results instead of an error).

Answer (score 0):

During `GROUP BY` in MySQL, it picks first matching row for each group unless you are using an aggregate function. The first matching need not be always row with min(id) .

The possible query should be something like :

```
SELECT t.*
from table_name t 
inner join (
  select min(id) as id 
  from table_name t 
  group by col) as s
on s.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below query.. let me know is this is your requirement?

*`SELECT *
FROM sk_product_special_price pspo
WHERE pspo.priority IN(SELECT MAX(psp.priority)
                        FROM sk_product_special_price psp
                          JOIN sk_product_category_path pcp
                            ON(pcp.product_seq_id=psp.product_seq_id)
                        WHERE psp.date_start IS NOT NULL
                          AND psp.date_start BETWEEN '0000-00-00' AND CURDATE()
                          AND (psp.date_end>=CURDATE() OR psp.date_end='0000-00-00')
                          AND pcp.product_seq_id=pspo.product_seq_id);`*

I have updated the end date "'2014-02-11" to "2014-02-12" for my code to fetch end date >=today's date.

this query will return the table2 details i.e table sk_product_special_price for each all the product based on the priyority values.

the output will be

`product_special_price_seq_id, product_special_price, date_start, date_end, priority, product_seq_id
2, 12200, '2014-02-11', '2014-02-12', 1, 3197
3, 123123, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 0, 3196`